# KOMA handling of even/odd pages

Tags: margins, koma-script, double-sided

I don't know if this is a bug or a configuration option that I've missed, but I've just noticed that in my document, KOMA script is putting odd pages on the right and even on the left, and yet the margins are configured so that the inside margins are less than the outside margins.

I didn't notice this before because I wasn't viewing my document in dual-page mode, but now that I've noticed it how can I change it so it gets the arrangement right?

Comment: Isn't putting odd pages on the right the thing one would expect? (Look into any book.)

Comment: This behavior is expected and correct, and it is shared by all document classes (at least in two-page mode).

Comment: Once I noticed this I did check quite a lot of books and found this is indeed the case, that the odd page numbers are on the right. The confusing bit is that the inside margins are less than the outside ones; shouldn't *that* be the other way around (i.e. to leave room for binding) ?

Comment: @zoqaeski: I think the default is not to have the binding included in the margin (most books are bound in such a way that there is very little space lost in the binding). The KOMA-Script classes have a binding correction (`BCOR`) option to specify how much space the binding will remove. Also most books have either equal margins or larger outer margins. I guess the reasoning is that you have to hold the book somewhere.

Comment: Btw, you might have to tell your pdf-viewer to put odd pages on the right side in dual-page mode. In Adobe Reader this is `View > Page Display > Show Cover Page During Two-Up`.

Comment: @Caramdir Evince doesn't have any features like that. As far as I know it doesn't have any preferences at all, and by default it shows a preview pane in the sidebar which is really annoying.

Comment: But Evince displays dual-page view correctly by default.

Comment: On the topic of why the inner margin is smaller than the outer margin, you might be interested in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42063/illogical-twoside-behaviour

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the way it should be for `scrreprt` and `scrbook`. You can control this feature with the `twoside`-option. See the [KOMA-Script manual](http://ctan.larsko.net/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguien.pdf), pp. 31 ff. and Markus Kohms [german article](http://www.dante.de/tex/Dokumente/KohmSatzspiegel.pdf) about type area construction.

```
\documentclass[twoside=false]{scrbook}% treat even and odd pages the same way
\documentclass[twoside=true]{scrbook}% different head/foot and margins on even and odd pages
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrbook}% different head/foot but same margins
```

Comment: @lockstep: Thanks for editing but I was on the way to correct it myself at the time of you edit :-)