# Tweaking even/odd format and header format in a CUED Thesis Template

Tags: formatting, thesis

I have prepared my PhD thesis in the LaTeX template of Cambridge University, available [here](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle/). (I'm using an older version 1.1, which can be accessed [here](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle1.1/).)

Now, I am experiencing two major problems with this template, when I compile everything in the twoside format (by so defining it in the documentclass):

1. The starting page (odd numbered, like Pg 1) looks like Figure (b) instead of Figure (a).

Figure (a)

[image]

Figure (b)

[image]

Of course, I would want all odd numbered pages (which is where e.g. Chapter 1 commences) to look like Fig. (a) and all even numbered pages to look like Fig. (b) (the back page). What this class file is compiling is the exact opposite. Any work-arounds for swapping the two?

2. The second problem is with tweaking the format of the text displayed in the header of the chapter content pages (viz. the section title and chapter title, respectively for the odd and even numbered pages). I have been successful in implementing my desired format using the structure:

   > \fancyhead[LE] {\bf \chaptername\ \thechapter. Chapter Name }

Thus, everything of this type is sorted out for the chapters and the references. But the problem is with the auto-generated pages, like the table of contents, list of figures and tables etc. 
An illustration of the problem is, e.g. in the contents pages, where the odd numbered pages read `Contents` in the header (in accordance with my wishes), but the even numbered pages read `CONTENTS`, according to some default prescription somewhere in the class file which I am not able to tweak. This looks hilarious!

So, my question is - how can I tweak this (*and only this*) given class file to implement these two changes. I am more of a LaTeX beginner (as compared to the level of this site) and can't make out how to go about tweaking the class file to produce the desired changes. Secondly, unless it is difficult to the extent of impossible, I wouldn't want to change the LaTeX template at this stage (since I'm done with writing now), so please avoid these type of suggestions.

---

More information - The class file for the template is as follows:

```
`%CUEDthesis v1.1
 % By Harish Bhanderi <harish.bhanderi@cantab.net
 % Version 1.0 released 15/07/2002
 % Version 1.1 released 14/07/2010
 %-------------------------- identification ---------------------
 %\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
 \ProvidesClass{CUEDthesisPSnPDF}[2010/07/14 v1.1 CUED thesis class]
 %-------------------------- initial code -----------------------
 \newif\ifCU@bookmode
 \CU@bookmodetrue
 \DeclareOption{report}{\CU@bookmodefalse}
 \DeclareOption{book}{\CU@bookmodetrue}
 \ProcessOptions\relax%
 \ifCU@bookmode
 \DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}%
 \ProcessOptions\relax%
 \ifx\pdfoutput\undefined%
 \LoadClass[dvips, a4paper]{book}%
 \else%
 \LoadClass[pdftex, a4paper]{book}%
 \fi%
 \else
 \DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}%
 \ProcessOptions\relax%
 \ifx\pdfoutput\undefined%
   \LoadClass[dvips, a4paper]{report}%
 \else%
    \LoadClass[pdftex, a4paper]{report}%
 \fi%
 %\renewcommand{\refname}{References}%
 \fi
 %\DeclareOption{book}{%
 %}%
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage{tocbibind}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{geometry}
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 %\usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{eucal}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
 \usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
 \usepackage[square, sort&compress, numbers]{natbib}
 %\usepackage[square, sort, numbers, authoryear]{natbib}
 \usepackage{ifthen}
 \usepackage{ifpdf}
 \usepackage{amssymb,amsbsy,amsmath}
 \usepackage{enumerate}
 %Bibliography
 %uncomment next line to change bibliography name to references for Book                       
 %document class
 renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
 % note that this doesn't do much if you later define another                                           % bibliography style 
 % Nomenclature
 % \usepackage{nomencl}
 % \makenomenclature
 % \renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
 %   \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{%
 %    \item[\textbf{Roman Symbols}] }{%             A - Roman
 %     \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{%
 %      \item[\textbf{Greek Symbols}]}{%             G - Greek
 %       \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{%
 %         \item[\textbf{Superscripts}]}{%              R - Superscripts
 %           \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{%
 %            \item[\textbf{Subscripts}]}{{%             S - Subscripts
 %      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{X}}{%
 %       \item[\textbf{Other Symbols}]}{{%    X - Other Symbols
 %      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{Z}}{%
 %       \item[\textbf{Acronyms}]}%              Z - Acronyms
 %                          {{}}}}}}}}}}
 %
 \ifpdf
 %-->
 %--> Google.com search "hyperref options"
 %--> 


    \usepackage[ pdftex, plainpages = false, pdfpagelabels,     
                 pdfpagelayout = OneColumn, % display single page, advancing            flips the page - Sasa Tomic
                bookmarks,
                 bookmarksopen = true,
                 bookmarksnumbered = true,
              %   hidelinks, % remove it after print out
                 breaklinks = true,
                 linktocpage,
%                  pagebackref,
                 colorlinks =  true,
                linkcolor = blue,
                 urlcolor  = blue,
                 %citecolor = red,
                 citecolor = blue,
                 anchorcolor = green,
                 hyperindex = true,
                 hyperfigures
                 ]{hyperref} 
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png, .jpg, .pdf}

    \pdfcompresslevel=9
    \graphicspath{{ThesisFigs/PNG/}{ThesisFigs/PDF/}{ThesisFigs/}}
\else
    \usepackage[ dvips,
                 bookmarks,
                 bookmarksopen = true,
                 bookmarksnumbered = true,
         %hidelinks,
                 breaklinks = true,
                 linktocpage,
%                  pagebackref,
                colorlinks = true,
                 linkcolor =black,% blue,
                urlcolor  = black,%blue,
                 citecolor = black,%red,%black,
                 anchorcolor = green,
                  hyperindex = true,
                 hyperfigures
                ]{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{hidelinks}
    %\usepackage{epsfig}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps, .ps}
    \graphicspath{{ThesisFigs/EPS/}{ThesisFigs/}}
\fi

%define the page size including an offset for binding
%\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in}
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
%\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
%\setlength{\textheight}{700pt}
%\setlength{\textwidth}{500pt}

%A4 settings
\ifpdf
   \pdfpageheight=297mm
   \pdfpagewidth=210mm
\else
   \setlength{\paperheight}{297mm}
   \setlength{\paperwidth}{210mm}
\fi

\setlength{\hoffset}{0.00cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{0.00cm}

\setlength{\evensidemargin}{1.96cm}
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.54cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{1mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{1.36cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{1.00cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{20.84cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{14.5cm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{1mm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{2.36cm}

\pagestyle{fancy}
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter. #1 }}{}}
%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{{#1}}{}}%{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter. #1 }}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\MakeUppercase{\thesection. #1 }}{}}%{}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\bfseries\leftmark}


%\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape \nouppercase \rightmark}
%\fancyhead[LE] {\itshape \nouppercase Chapter}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhead{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\newcommand{\submittedtext}{{A thesis submitted for the degree of}}
%
%
% DECLARATIONS
%
% These macros are used to declare arguments needed for the
% construction of the title page and other preamble.

% The year and term the degree will be officially conferred
\def\degreedate#1{\gdef\@degreedate{#1}}
% The full (unabbreviated) name of the degree
\def\degree#1{\gdef\@degree{#1}}
% The name of your college or department(eg. Trinity, Pembroke, Maths, Physics)
\def\collegeordept#1{\gdef\@collegeordept{#1}}
% The name of your University
\def\university#1{\gdef\@university{#1}}
% Defining the crest
\def\crest#1{\gdef\@crest{#1}}

% These macros define an environment for front matter that is always 
% single column even in a double-column document.

\newenvironment{alwayssingle}{%
       \@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
      \else\newpage\fi}
       {\if@restonecol\twocolumn\else\newpage\fi}

%define title page layout
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
\pagenumbering{roman} % Sasa Tomic
\setcounter{page}{0}  % Sasa Tomic
\begin{alwayssingle}
    \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\small}
    \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\relax}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
%  \null\vfill
  \begin{center}
    { \Huge {\bfseries {\@title}} \par}

\vspace*{20mm}
    {{\bf \large \submittedtext} \par}
\vspace*{1ex}
    {\textbf{ \emph{ \large \@degree}} \par}
     \vspace*{15mm}
   {{\bf \Large \@author} \par}
     \vspace*{25mm}
{\large {{\@crest} \par} \vspace*{20mm}}

{\bf \large \vspace*{1ex}
    {{\@collegeordept} \par}
\vspace*{1ex}
    {{\@university} \par}
\vspace*{2ex}
    {\@degreedate}}
  \end{center}
 % \null\vfill
\end{alwayssingle}}

% DEDICATION
%
% The dedication environment makes sure the dedication gets its
% own page and is set out in verse format.

\newenvironment{dedication}
{\begin{alwayssingle}
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{0.5cm}
  {\LARGE }
  \end{center}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
  \begin{quote} \begin{center}}
{\end{center} \end{quote} \end{alwayssingle}}


% ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
%
% The acknowledgements environment puts a large, bold, centered 
% "Acknowledgements" label at the top of the page. The acknowledgements
% themselves appear in a quote environment, i.e. tabbed in at both sides, and
% on its own page.

\newenvironment{acknowledgements}
{\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{alwayssingle}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{0.1cm}
{\Large \bfseries Acknowledgements}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\hrule
\end{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}


\newenvironment{lops}
{\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{alwayssingle}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1.5cm}
{\Large \bfseries List of Publications}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\hrule
\end{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}


% The acknowledgementslong environment puts a large, bold, centered 
% "Acknowledgements" label at the top of the page. The acknowledgement itself 
% does not appears in a quote environment so you can get more in.

\newenvironment{acknowledgementslong}
{\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{alwayssingle}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1.5cm}
{\Huge \bfseries Acknowledgements}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}\begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}

%ABSTRACT
%
%The abstract environment puts a large, bold, centered "Abstract" label at
%the top of the page. The abstract itself appears in a quote environment,
%i.e. tabbed in at both sides, and on its own page.

\newenvironment{abstracts} {\begin{alwayssingle} \pagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{1.5cm}
  {\Large \bfseries  Abstract}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
   \begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}

%The abstractlong environment puts a large, bold, centered "Abstract" label at
%the top of the page. The abstract itself does not appears in a quote
%environment so you can get more in.

\newenvironment{abstractslong} {\begin{alwayssingle} \pagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{1.5cm}
  {\Large \bfseries  Abstract}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{0.5cm} \begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}

%The abstractseparate environment is for running of a page with the abstract
%on including title and author etc as required to be handed in separately

\newenvironment{abstractseparate} {\begin{alwayssingle} \pagestyle{empty}
  \vspace*{-1in}
 \begin{center}
    { \Large {\bfseries {\@title}} \par}
    {{\large \vspace*{1ex} \@author} \par}
{\large \vspace*{1ex}
    {{\@collegeordept} \par}
    {{\@university} \par}
\vspace*{1ex}
    {{\it \submittedtext} \par}
    {\it {\@degree} \par}
\vspace*{2ex}
    {\@degreedate}}
  \end{center}}
{\end{alwayssingle}}

%ROMANPAGES
%
% The romanpages environment set the page numbering to lowercase roman one
% for the contents and figures lists. It also resets
% page-numbering for the remainder of the dissertation (arabic, starting at 1).

\newenvironment{romanpages}
{\setcounter{page}{1}
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}}
{\newpage\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}}
%{\newpage\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}\setcounter{page}{1}}

    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\part{%
      \if@openright
        \cleardoublepage
      \else
        \clearpage
      \fi
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \if@twocolumn
        \onecolumn
        \@tempswatrue
      \else
        \@tempswafalse
      \fi
      \null\vfil
      \secdef\@part\@spart}
    \makeatother`
```

Comment: On the first part: the class has this right. The inner margin should be smaller than the outer one in a twoside document. However: it's usual to print a thesis as a one-side document, are you really sure you want two-sided?

Comment: Without further feedback this looks like a dupe to me

Comment: @JosephWright - No problem, sir. As you know already from the chat transcript of Jun 25, I had posted quite detailed feedback, and got very personalized advice from yourself and Mr. Carlisle, which solved my problem as a work around. Many thanks. :)