# Reason for align in book?

Tags: book-design

When I use the documentclass book, I notice that it will align even numbered pages to the right and odd numbered pages to the left, so that when printed, the text of my document will be closer to the center.

Is there a typographical reason for this, or even a logical one? I would have assumed the opposite alignment so that you would never have the problem that text would become hard to read in the center (oddly worded, sorry) when printed.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42063/illogical-twoside-margins perhaps?

Comment: Not sure to see exactly what you mean. Normally the text is justified between margins. Maybe you mean margins are different on odd and even pages?

Comment: That is what I meant, indeed. The question linked by Joseph sort of answers my question, as it gives some reasons to use these margins. Still, I thought that there may have been an even simpler reason.

Comment: there's some commentary on traditional book margins by hermann zapf in a [tugboat article](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb22-1-2/tb70zapf.pdf).  it starts at the bottom of the third page of the article.

Comment: Some people like to write in the margins of their books. If you cram text all the way to the outside of the pages; leaving a large gap in the middle it becomes really troublesome to annotate.