# why aren't the pages aligned?

Tags: typography

[image]

This is my whole tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,polynom,amssymb,venndiagram,mathtools}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\title{Diophantine Equations}
\author{Sew Qian Hong}
\date{13 June 2018}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents




\chapter{Factorization}
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.



\chapter{Linear Diophantine Equations}

Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
Diophantine equations are polynomial equations with integral coefficients for which integral solutions are required.
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Consider adding `\end{document}`. And perhaps have a look at the geometry package.... or just add `\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}`, say. And as for "why" this happens: books, i.e. these curious things people were using in the previous Millenium, typically distinguish between even and odd sides, that is there is an inner edge and an outer edge ...

Comment: I think this could be useful to you: https://it.sharelatex.com/learn/Single_sided_and_double_sided_documents

Comment: For examples of page layouts you might care to look at *A Few Notes on Book Design* (`> texdoc memdesign`).

Comment: In order to align my pages I simply used `oneside` in the document class: `\documentclass[oneside]{abntex2}`

Comment: @DanielTerraGomes: This is covered in the current answer; hence my removal of your (duplicate) answer and changing it into a comment.

Comment: Potential duplicate: [Illogical twoside margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42063)

Answer (score 3):

The `article` and `report` LaTeX document classes, by default, use the `oneside` page layout option. One of the characteristics of this option is that the left-hand and right-hand margins are equal by default.

In contrast, the `book` LaTeX document class uses the `twoside` option. One of its characteristics is that if the document were printed and bound as a physical book, the "inner" margins -- those closer to the book's spine -- end up being narrower than the outer margins. I was once told that this is because when people hold a book open in their hands, they typically use their thumbs to do so. So as not to have the thumbs obscure the written text, the outer margins -- where the thumbs typically are placed -- are usually made a bit wider. I have no idea if that's the real reason, though.

If you need to use the `book` document class but don't like the `twoside` layout option, specify `oneside` explicitly:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
```