# pdf output of book documentclass

Tags: margins, document-classes, book-design, output

I am getting slightly confused with the pdf output of the `book` document class.

I am writing the textbook for my Discrete Math course and I chose to use the `book` class with the default options.

I understand that this has the following effects:

- the right pages are odd numbered, the left pages are even numbered,
- chapters start only at odd numbered pages.

This is in fact what I get, but while I would expect a bigger **left** margin for odd numbered pages and a bigger **right** margin for even numbered pages to compensate for the binding, I seem to get just the opposite.

What is going on?

Could just be an effect due to the pdf viewer running on my Mac? I usually produce outputs in the `a4paper` format option.

Comment: the margins are for your thumbs not for binding. standard typographic practice makes the outer margins about twice as wide as the inner ones so a 2-page spread has three similar white bands,  (binding methods may need additional lost paper but that is another matter)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : but I'm planning to use a service of print-on-demand and they need a pdf ready for prnt. What am I supposed to do, then?

Comment: the geometry package allows you to specify whatever margins (and binding offset) you want. Or classes such as koma or memoir have their own ways for specifying the same. I was just explaining why the defaults are as they are. (for which we have a duplicate question/answer somewhere:-)

Comment: whether you need additional binding space depends a lot on the binding methods to be used presumably a print service will have some advice about that.

Comment: Even when you do not use the memoir class, I highly recommend the companion document [A Few Notes on Book Design](https://ctan.org/pkg/memdesign). I learned much from it about the terminology as well as the best practices to produce a well-structured textbook.

Comment: The book class is outdated, people use memoir or KOMA-script for larger works.

Comment: KOMA's `scrbook` does have an option for binding corrections (`BCOR`). But those corrections aren't enormously big usually.

Comment: @Skillmon `memoir` also provides for binding corrections via its `\setbinding{<length>}` macro.

Comment: Think of the open spread as two columns with the left, center and right white space the same.

Comment: For some more discussion on the reason for this, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42063/illogical-twoside-margins