# Set up twopage offset for different pages manually

Tags: geometry, report, page, binding

Currently writing my thesis using the twoside report document class which pushes everything on an odd page to the left and everything on an even page to the right.

I have set up my document in a way which requires this to be tuned slightly.

My title page needs centering - which was easy enough using the \newgeometry{centering} command.

I then need the following pages to all be pushed to the right regardless of page number since I have abstract (page i) followed by a blank page then table of contents (page ii) etc. These all need to be pushed to the right as if they had even page numbers.

Then my main body of text restarts numbering at 1 (after another blank page), however it just so happens that because of the number of pages leading up to the start of the document that this should be pushed to the right (as if it was an even numbered page), following this they need to alternate like normal.

This is how the document is set up currently:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand\blankpage{
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}
    \newpage}  

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{centering}
Title page
\afterpage{\blankpage}
\restoregeometry
\raggedbottom
\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter*{Abstract}
Abstract
\setcounter{page}{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\afterpage{\blankpage}
%%%%%%%%%%% ADDING CONTENTS PAGE
\tableofcontents
\afterpage{\blankpage}
%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter*{List of Abbreviations}
\afterpage{\blankpage}
\setcounter{page}{3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}
Abbreviations
%%%%%%%%%
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\afterpage{\blankpage}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
Thanks
%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Intro}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\chapter{2}
Chapter 2
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I undestand you correctly, the first page of your main text is numbered with 1 (odd)  but actually is because of the amount of pages before it, an even (left) page. I as a reader would be confused by this as I would aways expect an odd number on a right page and an even number on a left page. If you want your thesis o be printed double-page, I would add an empty page to the backsied of the titlepage. This way page number 1 should be a right page instead of a left one.

Comment: Apart from my previous comment, please make a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including the documentclass and all relevant packages. We also don't have access to all your inputed files. So please replace them by some dummy text.

Comment: @leandriis Yeah so thats kind of it, its going to be printed back to back, so my first pages Title -> Acknowledgements will be on its own with blank paper on the back, therefore appears on the right hand side if you were reading like a book - therefore all of these needs to be pushed to the right to allow space in the left margin for binding.

Page 1 on the main text also starts on the right hand side as if it was a book, but because it has an odd page number it is pushed to the left and not the right.

Comment: @leandriis I will edit the original post with a MWE, albeit not that minimal but it includes everything I think you will need.

Comment: Thank you for your update. So, if I interpret this corretly, you expect the inner margin (the one that is near the spine od the book) to be wieder than the outer margin. Regarding this, you might be interested in the following: [Illogical twoside margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42063/134144)

Comment: @leandriis Thank you for your help. So it would appear as though I have confused the way 'twoside' works. It is designed to follow the standard that the outer margin is larger than the inner, I thought that it did this to help for binding reasons. 

Ofcourse if this is a generic standard I am happy to keep to it and then provide myself a manual binding offset within the geometry package. 

However, this still leaves me with the issue that in my pretext (title->acknowledgements) that even numbers are misaligned to be on the right hand page. I would like to keep my blank pages though between

Comment: Maybe a `\cleardoublepage` can help you.