# second page starts with more indented margin

Tags: horizontal-alignment, margins

[![enter image description here][1]][1]as I applied the enumerate to generate the numbered list for my latex file, unfortunately the second page pdf output generate bit different than the first page. here is the MWE:

`````
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setbox1=\hbox{1.}
\setlist{noitemsep, topsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, leftmargin=1.8cm, labelindent=1.2cm, labelwidth=\wd1, itemindent=*, labelsep=\dimexpr0.6cm-\wd1}

\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf {What is Lorem Ipsum?
}\\

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

\item \textbf {Why are you motivated?} \\

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. \\

\item \textbf{Why is this topic interested?} \\

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\\

\item \textbf{Why do we use it?} \\

1. Where does it come from?
2. Where can I get some?

3. Why do we use it?

4. Section 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC is okay?

5. Section 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC is valid? 

\item \textbf{Why do we use it?
} \\

"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

````


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rnm7d.png
`````

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. book is a document class designed as "twosided" ... this means that the printed version will have margins for notes or anything to the left of the left pages and to the right of the right ones.

Comment: Thank you. Cant we change the the book class margin effects?

Comment: You can add "oneside" option like `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, oneside]{book}` with your choice of the other options...

Comment: thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome .. happy TeXing ... Just keep in mind that may be a printed version could be better to have the "twosided" option or at least to have good enough inner margins to be read easy.

Comment: is it good practice to write master thesis as per default book class settings?

Comment: I am using more the "report" documentclass for this type of documents and really prefer it from any ready "thesis" template (You just have to add your specific requirements to the preamble).. except if the university ask for a specific template.

Comment: Potential duplicate: [Illogical twoside margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42063)

Comment: unrelated to the margins but remove all the `\\ ` in this document they will be giving a warning of badness 10000 (the _maximum_ level of badness in tex's assesment of the output) Never use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph.

Comment: sorry for inappropriate question @DavidCarlisle. Is there another option to make the paragraphs more aesthetic?

Comment: there are lots of options to change all aspects of the typesetting, which you consider more aesthetic I can not guess.

Comment: I would not set parindent and parskip by hand like that (use parskip package instead) and I would not use enumitem to set topsep to 0pt. also setting parsep to 0pt seems oddly inconsistent with your global setting of parskip. (but they are simply stylistic choices, whereas the `\\ ` at end of paragraph is unequivocally wrong)

Comment: thank you, but totally new into `parskip` and `enumitem` for the first day with TEX Shop. I need to learn it throughly.

Comment: if it is your fist day where are you picking up low level (and also wrong) code like `\setbox1=\hbox{1.}` it must be a very strange tutorial... (you also don't need the `inputenc` line if you have a current latex.)