# misalignment in second page

Tags: math-mode

I just started using TEX and I'm currently writing my first project.
I'm using overleaf to write my project however when I compile it the second page seems to be misaligned. Every row seems to be a bit to the right. =
I really can't find the reason for that. I'm posting my project below. If anyone can help I would appreciate it

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\title{Λογισμός Μεταβολών}
\author{Παπαδομιχελάκης Γεώργιος }
\date{Ιούνιος 2019}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}
\begin{document}
\section{Φυσικές Συνοριακές Συνθήκες}

Θα ασχοληθούμε με το πρόβλημα $$J[y]= \int_{a}^{b} L(x,y,y') \, dx$$ όπου $y \in C^2([a,b])$ με $y(a) = y_0$  , $ y(b)$ μη προσδιορισμένο
\newline Τέτοια προβλήματα ονομάζονται προβλήματα ελεύθερου άκρου
\newline
\newline
Έστω $y_0$ η συνάρτηση που ελαχιστοποιεί το $J[y]$. Θα πρέπει $J(y) \ge J(y_0)$ για κάθε αποδεκτή συνάρτηση  ${y} = y(x)+\epsilon h,$ $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R},$ $h \in C^1([a,b])$ με $h(a)=0$ και $h(b)$ ελεύθερο.
\newline
\newline
Τότε η $f(\epsilon) := J(y_0 + \epsilon h)$ έχει ελάχιστο στο $\epsilon = 0$ άρα $f'(0)=0$
$$
0 = f'(0)
= \frac{d}{d\epsilon} \int_{a}^{b} L(x,y+ \epsilon h, y' + \epsilon h') \,dx \Big|_{\epsilon = 0}
$$

$$ =\int_{a}^{b} L_y(x,y,y')h + L_{y'}(x,y,y')h \, dx
$$

$$
= \int_{a}^{b}(L_y - \frac{d}{dx}L_{y'})h \, dx \, + \, L_{y'}h \Big|_{x=a}^{x=b}
$$

$$ = \int_{a}^{b} (L_y - \frac{d}{dx}L_{y'}) \, dx \, + \,  L_{y'}(b,y(b),y'(b))h(b)=0 \quad (1)
$$
$\forall h \in C^2([a,b])$ με $h(a)=0$.
\newline
Εφόσον η (1) ισχύει για κάθε $h \in C^2([a,b])$ με $h(a)=0$ θα πρέπει να ισχύει και για αυτές τις $h$ oι οποίες ικανοποιούν ταυτόχρονα και την συνθήκη $h(b)=0$
\newline
\newline
Επιλέγουμε την $h$ τέτοια ώστε $h(b)=0$.
\newline
Τότε από το θεμελιώδες Λήμμα του Λογισμού Μεταβολών έχουμε ότι η $y$ πρέπει να ικανοποιεί την $$L_y - \frac{d}{dx}L_{y'}=0 \quad (Euler-Lagrange) $$

Αντικαθιστώντας την εξίσωση $Euler-Lagrange$ στην (1) προκύπτει ότι $$L_{y'}(b,y(b),y'(b))h(b)=0$$
και επειδή η τελευταία ισχύει για οποιαδήποτε επιλογή $h(b)$ έπεται οτι $$L_{y'}(b,y(b),y'(b))=0$$
Αυτή καλείται φυσική συνοριακή συνθήκη επί του ακροτάτου $y$ στο $x=b$.
\newline
\newline
Η εξίσωση $Euler-Lagrange$ μαζί με την δεδομένη συνοριακή συνθήκη $y(a)=y_0$ και την παραπάνω φυσική συνοριακή συνθήκη αρκούν για την εύρεση ακροτάτου στο αρχικό πρόβλημα
\newline
\newline
Με εντελώς ανάλογο τρόπο μπορούμε να δούμε οτι αν η τιμή στο άκρο $y(a)$ είναι ελεύθερη τότε η φυσική συνοριακή συνθήκη στο $x=a$ επεται να είναι $$L_{y'}(a,y(a),y'(a))=0$$
\newline
\newline
Στην ακόμα πιο γενική περίπτωση όπου κανένα απ' τα δύο άκρα δεν είναι δεδομένα, δηλαδή αν και τα δύο άκρα είναι ελεύθερα με ανάλογους συλλογισμούς θα καταλήξουμε στις εξής δύο φυσικές συνοριακές συνθήκες
$$ L_{y'}(a,y(a),y'(a))=0 \quad και \quad L_{y'}(a,y(a),y'(a))=0 $$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This question isn't exactly the same, but it gives the reason for the asymmetry: [Illogical twoside margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42063)

Comment: never ignore errors and warnings, the `\begin{document}` needs to be before the titlepage (that produces a hard error) and all those newlines produce `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 45--52` warnings which is the _maximum_ level of badness never use `\newline` at the end of a paragraph or after another `\newline`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no “misalignment”: you are asking for `twoside` which sets margins in symmetric fashion: wider on the outside than on the inside.

Thus the left margin on page 2 is wider than the right margin; the opposite happens on page 3.

Since you're a beginner in LaTeX, I take the occasion to show how your code should be laid out.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\title{Λογισμός Μεταβολών}
\author{Παπαδομιχελάκης Γεώργιος }
\date{Ιούνιος 2019}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\section{Φυσικές Συνοριακές Συνθήκες}

Θα ασχοληθούμε με το πρόβλημα
\[
J[y]= \int_{a}^{b} L(x,y,y') \, dx
\]
όπου $y \in C^2([a,b])$ με $y(a) = y_0$, $ y(b)$ μη προσδιορισμένο

Τέτοια προβλήματα ονομάζονται προβλήματα ελεύθερου άκρου

Έστω $y_0$ η συνάρτηση που ελαχιστοποιεί το $J[y]$. Θα πρέπει $J(y) \ge J(y_0)$ για κάθε 
αποδεκτή συνάρτηση  $y = y(x)+\epsilon h$, $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$, $h \in C^1([a,b])$ 
με $h(a)=0$ και $h(b)$ ελεύθερο.

Τότε η $f(\epsilon) := J(y_0 + \epsilon h)$ έχει ελάχιστο στο $\epsilon = 0$ άρα $f'(0)=0$
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Lxy}
\begin{split}
0 = f'(0)
&= \frac{d}{d\epsilon} \int_{a}^{b} L(x,y+ \epsilon h, y' + \epsilon h') \,dx \Big|_{\epsilon = 0}
\\
&=\int_{a}^{b} L_y(x,y,y')h + L_{y'}(x,y,y')h \, dx
\\
&= \int_{a}^{b}(L_y - \frac{d}{dx}L_{y'})h \, dx \, + \, L_{y'}h \Big|_{x=a}^{x=b}
\\
&= \int_{a}^{b} (L_y - \frac{d}{dx}L_{y'}) \, dx \, + \,  L_{y'}(b,y(b),y'(b))h(b)=0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$\forall h \in C^2([a,b])$ με $h(a)=0$.

Εφόσον η \eqref{eq:Lxy} ισχύει για κάθε $h \in C^2([a,b])$ με $h(a)=0$ θα πρέπει να ισχύει και 
για αυτές τις $h$ oι οποίες ικανοποιούν ταυτόχρονα και την συνθήκη $h(b)=0$.

Επιλέγουμε την $h$ τέτοια ώστε $h(b)=0$.

Τότε από το θεμελιώδες Λήμμα του Λογισμού Μεταβολών έχουμε ότι η $y$ πρέπει να ικανοποιεί την 
\[
L_y - \frac{d}{dx}L_{y'}=0 \quad \textlatin{(Euler-Lagrange)}
\]
Αντικαθιστώντας την εξίσωση \textlatin{Euler-Lagrange} στην \eqref{eq:Lxy} προκύπτει ότι 
\[
L_{y'}(b,y(b),y'(b))h(b)=0
\]
και επειδή η τελευταία ισχύει για οποιαδήποτε επιλογή $h(b)$ έπεται οτι
\[
L_{y'}(b,y(b),y'(b))=0
\]
Αυτή καλείται φυσική συνοριακή συνθήκη επί του ακροτάτου $y$ στο $x=b$.

Η εξίσωση \textlatin{Euler-Lagrange} μαζί με την δεδομένη συνοριακή συνθήκη $y(a)=y_0$ 
και την παραπάνω φυσική συνοριακή συνθήκη αρκούν για την εύρεση ακροτάτου στο αρχικό πρόβλημα

Με εντελώς ανάλογο τρόπο μπορούμε να δούμε οτι αν η τιμή στο άκρο $y(a)$ είναι ελεύθερη τότε 
η φυσική συνοριακή συνθήκη στο $x=a$ επεται να είναι
\[
L_{y'}(a,y(a),y'(a))=0
\]
Στην ακόμα πιο γενική περίπτωση όπου κανένα απ' τα δύο άκρα δεν είναι δεδομένα, δηλαδή αν και 
τα δύο άκρα είναι ελεύθερα με ανάλογους συλλογισμούς θα καταλήξουμε στις εξής δύο φυσικές 
συνοριακές συνθήκες
\[
L_{y'}(a,y(a),y'(a))=0 \quad \text{και} \quad L_{y'}(a,y(a),y'(a))=0
\]

\end{document}
```

Never use `\newline\newline` to end paragraphs, nor `$$` for centering equations. Equation numbers can be set automatically and referenced with `eqref`.

Using `babel` ensures that hyphenation will follow the rules of the Greek language.

[image]