# xelatex typesetting offset

Tags: layout

Recently, I have been using xelatex to layout my paper. I have to add a lot of extra changes because of the many details required in my school paper.
For example, the words on the even-numbered pages (2, 4, 6, ...) are shifted a little to the right than the words on odd-numbered pages (1,3,5,...).
Is this caused by my modification of the page specification? Why is there a regular offset?

Comment: Welcome to TeX, SE. Please show a minimal working example.

Comment: This is the standard behaviour if you have `twoside` option set for your documentclass (which is the default in some document classes). Look at most books, the outside margin is bigger than the inside margin so the layout on odd and even pages is different

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42063/illogical-twoside-margins