# Margins revert to right on twoside in poemscol

Tags: margins, books, book-design, poemscol

I am typesetting a book of poetry using **poemscol**. I have run in to an issue where when poemscol is enabled in the preamble, the margin on the verso (left side) page moves over to the right side of that page.

*NOTE:* I've enable a frame to show where the textblock, header, footer and margins are.

```latex
\documentclass[draft,letter,10pt,twoside]{book}
 \usepackage{showframe}
    \usepackage{color}
    \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.25pt}
    \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 %\usepackage{makeidx}
 \usepackage{multicol}
 \usepackage[osf,p]{libertinus}
 \usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{tmargin=33pt,
 textwidth=318.21pt,textheight=550pt,
 marginparsep=7pt,marginparwidth=10pt,
 headheight=15pt,
 headsep=19pt,
 footskip=15pt,
 lmargin=132pt,twoside}
 \usepackage{keyval,ifthen,mparhack,manyfoot}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{poemscol}
 \begin{document}
 \leftheader{The Collected Poems of Robert Penn Warren}
 \lipsum[1-12]
 \end{document}
```

Comment: This question explains `twoside` and provides some history: [Illogical twoside margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42063)

Answer (score 0):

That is what the `twoside` option does, so use the `oneside` option.

Have you ever looked closely closely at a professionaly typeset book (such as any book that you can buy in your local bookstore)? Open the book in the middle of a chapter and you will see that the sideways location on the adjascent pages is different. In general the outer margins are twice the inner margins so when the book is opened the left, (total) inner and right margins all look equal.

On the other hand, don't use the `oneside` option to get a "better" looking result than the accepted typographical look because it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still struggling with this. I've tried your suggestion; however, what I want is for the margin area (where line numbering and other marks will go) to appear on the *left* of verso pages and on the *right* of recto pages.

Using `\documentclass[twoside]{article}` and invoking `\usepackage{poemscol}` moves the text block and headers correctly on verso and recto, but the margin area *remains* on the right of each.

What I'm wondering is why is it that poemscol does this?

Comment: My memory is not what it was. Have you taken a look at the  `changepage` package`? Your question seems perfectly reasonable; apologies but I don't think that I can help any more.

Comment: Thanks - I worked it out. It's a precedence issue: geometry has to be called **after** `poemsol.` In my MWE, it is being called before and that's what created the issue.